# Protractor: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: protractor

I am new to Protractor. Please suggest ways to get the element like matching the text value? Because in this code, firstname is dynamic, so it might get change later.

```
 let patientDetails = helper.getSavedValues();
 let firstname = patientDetails[0].value;
 return helper.clickElement(element(by.xpath('//*[text() 
 [contains(.,'+firstname+')]]')));
```

It returns this error message:

> A WebDriverError: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle'on 
>       'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

I've seen some other similar questions but I couldn't solve it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an `a` element you can use `linkText` or `partialLinkText`

See the docuentation: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.linkText